# Выстроить числа по возрастанию

Tags: массивы, c, сортировка

Помогите, пожалуйста. Есть код, нужно отсортировать числа по возрастанию... вот программа, тут по убыванию, никак не могу понять как сделать по возрастанию.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main ()
{
    int p[50];
    int i, n, j;
    int count = 1;      
    float   res;

    printf("Size= ");
    scanf("%u",&n);
    printf("\nEnter elements: \n");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("Element[%d]= ", i+1);
        scanf("%u", &p[i]);
    }

    int temp=p[0];  
    for (i=1; i<n; i++)
        if(p[i]!=temp){
            for (j=i+1; j<n; j++)  
                if(p[i]==p[j])     
                    p[j]=temp;       
            count++;            
        }

    printf("\nYou Mas:\n");
    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
        printf("%i ", p[i]);

    printf("\n");
    count=0;
    for (i=1; i<n; i++)
        if (p[i]!=p[0]) p[++count]=p[i];

    printf("\nAfter del:\n");
    for (i=0; i <= count; i++) 
        printf("%i ", p[i]);
    printf("\nSort mas: \n");
    for (int i = 0; i <= count; i++)
       for (int j = i+1; j <= count; j++)
          if (p[i] < p[j]){
             int buf = p[i];
             p[i] = p[j];
             p[j] = buf;
          }   
    for (int i = 0; i <= count; i++)
        printf("%i ", p[i]);
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Незнайка-недоучка если вы писали эту программу сами, то очевидно должны понимать, как она работает. Если же её написал кто-то за вас, то о принципе ее работы имеет смысл спросить у автора

Comment: for (int i = 0; i <= count; i++)
   for (int j = i+1; j <= count; j++)
      if (p[i] !!!!>!!!! p[j]){
         int buf = p[i];
         p[i] = p[j];
         p[j] = buf;
      }   

Я восклицательными знаками поставил где поменять, попробуйте...